# uniquely identifying each test invocation in testng

Tags: java, testng

Ok, so I have a class like this

```
public class Calculator {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Invoked add: a, b" + a + "," + b);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] createData(ITestContext ctx) {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, 2 }, new Object[] { 2, 3 } };
    }
```

When, the test runs, it would run add method twice. I want to track each invocation of add uniquely based on its input. So say, add is invoked with 1,2 as input then that's a unique invocation. If it fails, I want to store this information to a database with an invocation id.

How do I achieve this using testng? All of the listeners (methodinvocationlistener etc), do not seem to provide context that uniquely identifies a method run. Yes, they do let you see the parameters, but I cannot track individual parameters. So, do I somehow inject my own unique parameter into the result object and track it from there?

**UPDATE**

I am adding improved code, to help understand the context better.
This is my testng.xml

```
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test name="test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.test.testng.Calculator">
        <methods>
          <include name="add">
            <parameter name="data-id" value="1"/>
          </include> <!-- add -->
          <include name="add">
            <parameter name="data-id" value="2"/>
          </include> <!-- add -->
          <include name="subtract">
            <parameter name="data-id" value="3"/>
          </include> <!-- subtract -->
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.test.testng.Calculator -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- test -->
</suite> <!-- Default Suite -->
```

I have two invocations of add  and one invocation of subtract. 
Here's my data provider

```
public class Calculator {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void add(int first, int second) {
        System.out.println("invoked add");
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void subtract(int first, int second) {
        System.out.println("invoked subtract");
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] createData(Method m, ITestContext ctx) {    
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, 2 }, new Object[] { 2, 3 }, new Object[] { 3, 4 } };
        for (XmlClass test : ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getXmlClasses()) {
            for (XmlInclude method : test.getIncludedMethods()) {
                if (method.getName().equals(m.getName()))
                int key = Integer.parseInt(method.getAllParameters().get("data-id"));
                return new Object[][] { data[key - 1] };
            }
        }
        return null ;
    }

}
```

I expected, add to run twice, once with 1,2 as input and another time with 2,3 as input. Similarly, subtract with 3,4 as input. But, what I saw was this -

```
[SuiteRunner] Created 1 TestRunners
[TestRunner] Running test test on 1  classes,  included groups:[] excluded groups:[]
===== Test class
com.test.testng.Calculator
    @Test Calculator.add(int, int)[pri:0, instance:com.test.testng.Calculator@39a054a5]
    @Test Calculator.subtract(int, int)[pri:0, instance:com.test.testng.Calculator@39a054a5]
======
method.getAllParamas(){data-id=1}

[Invoker 665576141] Invoking com.test.testng.Calculator.add
invoked

[Invoker 665576141] Invoking com.test.testng.Calculator.subtract
subtract
===== Invoked methods
    Calculator.add(int, int)[pri:0, instance:com.test.testng.Calculator@39a054a5]1 2  966808741
    Calculator.subtract(int, int)[pri:0, instance:com.test.testng.Calculator@39a054a5]1 2  966808741
=====
```

I need to provide data to each method based on the special parameter that I am going to send from testng xml. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is the use-case here?  Why would you want/need to persist state beyond the test-case run?

Comment: the use case is - Let's this 'Calculator' class has 10 methods. I would like the user to select which methods he wants to test from a UI, then for each method he marked for testing, he would upload data related to each method through a spreadsheet. This spreadsheet data is persisted to the database and a key is generated. At runtime, when I generate a testng xml, it will contain these keys and the DataProvider will create input after reading the persisted data from database. Now, as you can see, I have different invocations, for tests, all of them dynamically created. I need to track them.

Comment: Ok.  In that case can't you store a UID/key per entry in the database, read that as part of the DataProvider, and pass the UID as a parameter to the test method?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Can you please add example code to what your are suggesting.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I know what you are trying to say. At the DataProvider level, I can pass the UID, but again, this will have to be made part of my datamodel. For instance, let's say the add() method accepts add(Tuple tuple) as parameter instead of two ints. Then I need to now design this Tuple class with int id, int a, int b where id represents the unique id. I will have to do this all my POJOs. I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: @Jay I am not absolutely clear on what you want to do . But Can you add one more argument to your test methods apart from Tuple  ? In that case you can generate the UID at Dataprovider method for specific data sets and pass on along with the tuple as a second argument which your method will get and you can track the results with that.

Comment: @Shamik I do not want to add this extra parameter to my method. I do not want the actual test code to know much about all these other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can define diferent tests cases in testng.xml, like this:

```
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test name="test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.test.testng.Calculator">
        <methods>
          <include name="add">
            <parameter name="data-id" value="1"/>
          </include> <!-- add -->
          <include name="subtract">
            <parameter name="data-id" value="3"/>
          </include> <!-- subtract -->
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.test.testng.Calculator -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- test -->
  <test name="test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.test.testng.Calculator">
        <methods>
          <include name="add">
            <parameter name="data-id" value="2"/>
          </include> <!-- add -->
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.test.testng.Calculator -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- test -->
</suite> <!-- Default Suite -->
```

I add a log in provider method:

```
package com.test.testng;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlInclude;

public class Calculator {

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void add(int first, int second) {
        System.out.println("invoked add");
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void subtract(int first, int second) {
        System.out.println("invoked subtract");
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] createData(Method m, ITestContext ctx) {    
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { new Object[] { 1, 2 }, new Object[] { 2, 3 }, new Object[] { 3, 4 } };
        for (XmlClass test : ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getXmlClasses()) {
            for (XmlInclude method : test.getIncludedMethods()) {

                if (method.getName().equals(m.getName())) {
                    int key = Integer.parseInt(method.getAllParameters().get("data-id"));
                    System.out.println("Running method " + m.getName() + "  with data-id: " + key);
                    return new Object[][] { data[key - 1] };
                }


            }
        }
        return null ;
    }

}
```

Running this xml as testng suite (with eclipse plugin) shows this:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/fhernandez/Documents/workspaceTest/testNg-test/src/test/resources/testng.xml

Running method add  with data-id: 1
invoked add
Running method subtract  with data-id: 3
invoked subtract
Running method add  with data-id: 2
invoked add

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

If I understand well your requirements, with this you can achieve it.

Another way for achieve this would be put an aspect or a proxy before test classes and do inspection of method invocation, implementing in this aspect/proxy your requirements.

**UPDATE**

I add a Listener to Calculator with

```
@Listeners(Listener.class)
public class Calculator
```

The listener looks like the following

```
    package com.test.testng;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlInclude;

public class Listener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult itr) {
        // TODO implements
    }

    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        // Parameters value
        System.out.println("Parameters invocation value for method " + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
        Arrays.asList(testResult.getParameters()).stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        // get data-id
        for (XmlClass test : testResult.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getXmlClasses()) {
            for (XmlInclude met : test.getIncludedMethods()) {

                if (met.getName().equals(method.getTestMethod().getMethodName())) {
                    int key = Integer.parseInt(met.getAllParameters().get("data-id"));
                    System.out.println("listener: Running method " + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName() + "  with data-id: " + key);
                }        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code in beforeInvocation show the parameter invocation values and data-id, this is the output

```
    [TestNG] Running:
  /Users/fhernandez/Documents/workspaceTest/testNg-test/src/test/resources/testng.xml

Running method add  with data-id: 1
Parameters invocation value for method add
1
2
listener: Running method add  with data-id: 1
invoked add
Running method subtract  with data-id: 3
Parameters invocation value for method subtract
3
4
listener: Running method subtract  with data-id: 3
invoked subtract
Running method add  with data-id: 2
Parameters invocation value for method add
2
3
listener: Running method add  with data-id: 2
invoked add

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Thanks, I am doing something similar. However, the trouble is in tracking these executions using IInvokedMethodListener. At the listener level, there is no way to access these parameters. Is there?

Comment: Hi, I update the answer whit a listener using java 8 (for lambda and stream). I can get the parameters invocation values. Hope helps!

Comment: I am using a similar approach to what you mentioned in the answer. I don't see any other way to access the data-id at method listener level other than having all parameters (non-primitives) extend a base class and allow only test methods with a minimum of one java object parameter. Do you see any other way to access data-id inside beforeInvocation() method? I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanks!! Let me see, I believe that data-id is accesible at that level, but I am not sure... I will try it and I tell you

Comment: Take a look at my new update for the answer, I access to the data-id property in listener in a very similar way that the Data provider, is that what you need?

Comment: It looks like that is what I need, but do you think that code will work always? (met.getName().equals(method.getTestMethod().getMethodName())) - you are matching on name, against the virtual xml. Will it not return the same data id if I have the same method twice in the test? In other words, is it always guaranteed to return unique data ids?

Comment: You should not have the same method inside the same test tag for the same class in xml file. You could have one method with the same name inside the test tag for another class. You can verify the class name besides the method name in order to ensure that there is the one you want. I think it will work in all cases

Comment: ok, I am actually creating my testng xml dynamically, so I only have one method per test. So, I think this will work. Actually, the code you wrote already exists in testng code base. The same functionality can be achieved by doing this - method.getTestMethod().findMethodParameters(        context.getCurrentXmlTest()) and then looking inside the map that gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

First argument in [][] is number of testing runs. Second is number of parameters. I.e.
    public Object[][] createData(ITestContext ctx) {
        return new Object[][] { new Object[] { 0,2 }, new Object[] { 0,3}
        };
    }

---

Will run one test with two parameters 2,3.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are for the *developer* to check his/her own code, and no one else.

Comments to the question indicate "user specified parameters/tests" are in the context, which puts it in the *system* test realm.

Don't use a *unit testing* framework to execute *system* tests.

An important point is that in your proposed environment it is possible for something *external* to the code (a user adding new test parameters) to break the build. This is bad. Very bad. If new functionality is required, the *developer* will enhance the code and add new tests to cover it.

Have a look at the [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) framework [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/), which seems a better fit to your need.

Comment: thanks - this is not for unit/system testing. I am building a solution that leverages testng for execution of tests. So, it needs a lot of customization.